# Votive Candle display

Tags: circuit-design

The Votive candle unit in the church has two circuits
using a 555 timer at the coin-slot area, and in each
candle, there is a 556 dual timer on a custom-designed
PCB. I have no schematics.
The problem is that there are two sets of IR components
opposing each other at the underside of the coin slot
plate. These have been broken off, the wires sheared
at the epoxy. Date codes show some time in the '80s.
No manufacturer's ID. Doing a search of the part # on
one of these components comes up empty.
So, in operation it seems simple ... a coin (or paper
bill) is dropped through the slot. The IR detector
circuit is broken, sending a signal to the 'main'
555 timer board (probably set for 15 minutes?). Then
a person can press a pushbutton on the top of each
candle (3 rows of 15 candles), and it will light with
a flickering glow (556 on a separate board within
each candle cylinder).
It's obvious that this entire circuit dates back many
decades. There is a TIP120 Xsistor on the 555 board,
but I'm not sure what its function actually is, except
may be to supply the +15V to the candle lines.
I need some advice on what to use for the coin/bill
detectors. Hopefully I can retrofit to the other
circuits. Will have to do a lot of reverse engineering
to determine the actual circuits on the 555 PCB
& the 556 p.c. board.
Thanks

Comment: Use the tool and show what circuit you are talking about. You can push the edit button and then look for the circuit tool button

Comment: Xsistor? TIP120 is a NPN Darlington transistor?

Comment: Use what 'tool'?   I know that a TIP120 is an NPN Darlington transistor.  Not sure what is being referenced with 'using the tool.  What circuit?  The 555 timer circuits that I referred to are on p.c. boards in this unit.  I need more explanation from this site or moderator.